# Data Migration - Oracle to Azure

Tags: oracle, azure, azure-storage, data-migration

I have close to ~6TB of data to be migrated. This data resides in the form of files in Oracle Block Storages. What can be the fastest way to migrate this data over to Azure Files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the PM on Azure Files. You have a couple of options.

1. Use AzCopy
2. Mount Azure Files Share and copy data using traditional tools like robocopy or gio
3. Disk rental

Feel free to reach out to me at rena dot shah at microsoft dot com.

Thank You
Rena Shah